# SQL : Repeat patterns for given date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried few things and took some help from internet and got the solution to repeat the pattern of each employee for given date range.

but I am facing one challenge which is, if there is any weekend in between then I am losing the pattern's continuity. I have a requirement that if there is any weekend or any leave then my pattern should continue after the weekend or any applied leaves.

Please find the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/122f5/1) for more clarity on my requirement.

Also find the attached screen shot of my current output and expected requirement.

[image]

For given screen shot I have taken only one employee with default weekend (sat,sun or 6,7) but in SQL fiddle we have different week off for each employee...

Comment: @DaftLeech can you help me on this ?

Comment: SqlFidlle is not related to the picture you've posted.

Comment: Yes correct that's why I have mentioned in column name as what is expected output and what output I am getting currently just to clear the requirement...

Comment: "current output" column belong to fiddle "ShiftId" Column and "Expected Output" column is what I want... let me know if it's not clear will update the name of screen shot as per the fiddle one

Comment: "WD": is week Days value for.Ex. Saturday = 6 , sunday = 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check below: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/122f5/93)

Prepare two intermediate tables using the SQL you presented and the SQL described in my previous answer as follows:

```
    TempWeekOff(Txt , i , WeekOffId , EmployeeID)
    AS (
            SELECT STUFF(WeekOff, 1, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, WeekOff+@delimiter+'~'), ''), 1 , CAST(LEFT(WeekOff, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, WeekOff+@delimiter+'~')-1) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), 
            EmployeeID
            FROM RuleTableTemp
            UNION ALL
            SELECT STUFF(Txt, 1, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, Txt+@delimiter+'~'), '')
                , i + 1
                , CAST(LEFT(Txt, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, Txt+@delimiter+'~')-1) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
                , EmployeeID
            FROM TempWeekOff
            WHERE Txt > ''
         ),
    TempDates(i_count,Dates,dd,EmployeeID,SortCount,WeekOffId)
    AS (
        SELECT 
            i_count,
            DATEADD(DAY, i_count, @startDate) AS Dates , 
            DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(DAY, i_count, @startDate)) as dd,
            EmpID,
            sortCount,
            WeekOffId
        FROM (SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @endDate) + 1) AS t_datediff(t_days)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (t_days) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0) ) - 1 FROM E8) AS t_dateadd(i_count)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT EmployeeID FROM RuleTableTemp) AS t(EmpID)
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(Sort) FROM PatternXFrequency WHERE EmployeeID = EmpID ) AS EmpPattern(sortCount)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TempWeekOff ON EmpID = TempWeekOff.EmployeeID AND DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(DAY, i_count, @startDate)) = TempWeekOff.WeekOffId
    )
```

Please check if you can get the expected output with the following SQL.

```
SELECT
    d.EmployeeID,
    d.Dates,
    d.dd,
    p.ShiftId
    FROM (SELECT *,((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY Dates)-1) % SortCount) AS i FROM TempDates WHERE WeekOffId IS NULL) AS d
    INNER JOIN PatternXFrequency p ON p.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID AND d.i = p.Sort
UNION
SELECT
    d.EmployeeID,
    d.Dates,
    d.dd,
    NULL
    FROM (SELECT * FROM TempDates WHERE WeekOffId IS NOT NULL) AS d
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: ShiftId is there in table as comma separated... And here you have calculated using some logic which is not feasible here

Comment: Does the ShiftId means another column of another table?
The ShiftId in my answer is the "expected output", may be not the ShiftId that you say.

Comment: It's in same table but different columns

Comment: You can check the query in given fiddle link

Comment: See below: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e8cc/4)

Comment: The WD conditions can be specified on that a column by joining a table like "shift management table" if there is it.
If there is any leave, you can filter by WHERE clause with the WD conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217629/discussion-between-vijay-sahu-and-etsuhisa).

Comment: Seriously it's working.. I thought there will be no answer for this... so write the logic using while loop... can you help me to understand the logic behind this.. means just copy and paste will not make me happy... I just want to learn how you did that...or just reference to learn concept like this...

Comment: I wrote the explanation [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217629/discussion-between-vijay-sahu-and-etsuhisa).